# Why is this the area?

Tags: calculus, vectors

Suppose that we have a triangle with vertices the points $0, \vec{a}, \vec{b}$.

Why does it hold that the area of the triangle is equal to the half of the area of the parallelogram with sides $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ ?

Comment: Think about chopping off the angled part of a parallelogram from one side and gluing it to the other side, you get a perfect rectangle with four right angles.

Comment: So we can only see it geometrically, right? If so , could you maybe explain it further to me maybe with a graph ? @GregoryGrant

Answer (score 1):

Look at this image:

[image]

Suppose the sides labeled $a$ and $b$ are the two vectors.  You can see the triangle is exactly half the area of the parallelogram.  If you cut the part to the left of the dashed line and glue it on to the right side you'll have a perfect rectangle.  The area of that rectangle is then obviously $b\times h$ the same as the area of the parallelogram.    So the area of the triangle is exactly half of that.  I hope this helps!

Comment: Why does this hold?

$$$$
If you cut the part to the left of the dashed line and glue it on to the right side you'll have a perfect rectangle.

Comment: @Evinda Is it not obvious visually from the picture?

Answer (score 0):

The diagonal divides the parallelogram into two congruent parts where vectors a and b are parallelly shifted.